# Batch and Bash codes while submitting jobs

Tags: r, bash, batch-processing, slurm, torque

I was used to the following way of submitting my jobs that to be done in R in an sequential way in 'PBS/Torque'.
following is my R code named simsim.R

```
#########
set<-1
#########
# Read i
#########
#the following two refers to the bash code
arg <- commandArgs()
arg
itration<- as.numeric(arg)[3]
itration

setwd("/home/habijabi")
save(arg,itration,
     file = paste0('simsim_RESULT_',set,itration,'.RData'))
```

Now I write the following set of codes

```
#!/bin/bash
Chains=10
for cha in `seq 1 $Chains`
do
    echo "Chains:  " $cha
    sleep 1
    qsub -q long -l nodes=1:ppn=12,walltime=24:00:00 -v c=$cha ./diffv1.sh

done
```

in this 'diffv1.sh' I used to load the module and pass the variable 'c'.

```
#!/bin/bash 

## input values
c=$c

#configure software
module load R/4.1.2
#changed
cd /home/habijabi
R --no-save  < simsim.R $c
```

In this way I was used to sending the '$c' value to my R code. And it would have produced me 10 many .R files with the corresponding names.
But then I had to change to 'SLURM'. Following is the batch code that I was using.

```
#!/bin/bash 
#SBATCH --job-name=R-test

#IO files
#SBATCH --error=R-test.%J.err
#SBATCH --output=R-test.%J.out

#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                             
module load R/4.1.2
set -e -x

mkdir -p jobs

cd /home/habijabi


for cha in {1..10}
do
    sbatch --time=24:00:00 \
           --ntasks-per-node=12  \
           --nodes=1 \
           -p compute \
           -o jobs/${cha}_srun.txt \
           --wrap="R --no-save < /home/habijabi/simsim.R ${cha}"
done
```

But with this code, it runs only once or twice. And I do not understand why after submitting 150 jobs it does not run all of them.... The run file shows the following:

```
+ mkdir -p jobs
+ cd /home/habijabi
+ for cha in '{1..10}'
+ sbatch --time=24:00:00 --ntasks-per-node=12 --nodes=1 -p compute -o jobs/1_srun.txt '--wrap=R --no-save < /home/habijabi/simsim.R 1'
+ for cha in '{1..10}'
+ sbatch --time=24:00:00 --ntasks-per-node=12 --nodes=1 -p compute -o jobs/2_srun.txt '--wrap=R --no-save < /home/habijabi/simsim.R 2'
+ for cha in '{1..10}'
+ sbatch --time=24:00:00 --ntasks-per-node=12 --nodes=1 -p compute -o jobs/3_srun.txt '--wrap=R --no-save < /home/habijabi/simsim.R 3'
...so on...
```

and the .out file shows the following

```
Submitted batch job 146299
Submitted batch job 146300
Submitted batch job 146301
Submitted batch job 146302
Submitted batch job 146303
......
......
```

Both are doing fine...But here, a few of the jobs run, and majority of them gives error as follows.

```
/opt/ohpc/pub/libs/gnu8/R/4.1.2/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre2-8.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I do not understand what I have done wrong....This does not produce anything... I am new at this type of coding, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This most probably is due to issues in the installation of R ; you could identify the nodes on which the jobs fail et try to run a simple hello world type of R syntax and if it fails, report it to the system admins

Comment: the problem was the missing pcre library. R uses libpcre, but pcre is separate from R, it’s not an R library one can install (though there are pcre api interface R libraries, I think pcre-r is one of them).